# mySQL GROUP BY different values as same

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have data which looks like following

```
ping    Type    Network
24      3G      Telecom
23      3.5G    Tata
37      4G      Voda
48      3G      Tata
51      3.5G    Telecom
26      3G      Telecom
37      4G      Voda
48      3G      Voda
```

I want to group it in such a way that '3G' and '3.5G' make one group and '4G' makes another group. In my case only 'Voda' is '4G'.

I trying to get output like this

```
avgping Type    Network
24      3XG     Telecom
23      3XG     Tata
37      4G      Voda
48      3XG     Voda
```

How can that be done?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your desired output?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I have added the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use `group by`, you can use `case` in a `group by`:

```
select (case when type in ('3G', '3.5G') then '3G' else type end) as nettype,
       count(*)
from data d
group by (case when type in ('3G', '3.5G') then '3G' else type end) ;
```

Comment: column returned with GROUP BY has the name `(case when ...`. Also `group by (case when ...) as netType` is not allowed. How do I replace that with a simple name?

Comment: @TayyabArshad . . . It should have the name `nettype` above.  You just say `as nettype` after the expression to give it a name.